# How to know when a module content is changed in Sitefinity

Tags: c#, api, content-management-system, sitefinity

I want some trigger or some action to be done whenever there is a content change for a particular module in Sitefinity. Is there a way that I can track when content changes or is there any other right way to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook to any of these events: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-dynamic-modules-events

e.g. **IDynamicContentUpdatingEvent** or **IDynamicContentUpdatedEvent** and execute your logic.

Be mindful though, as these events may fire several times, once for the Temp item and again for the Master item, so you may want to check that.